# Proof of distribution of $Y^{T}AY$

Tags: linear-model, multivariate-normal-distribution, quadratic-form

I am reading a proof that given $Y \sim N(\mu, \Sigma)$, where $\Sigma$ is positive definite, $Y^{T}AY \sim \chi^{2}_{p}(\mu^{T}A\mu)$

iff $A \Sigma A =A$ and $A$ has rank $p$.

One of the steps in this proof is that $Y^{T}AY = Y^{T}\Sigma^{-\frac{1}{2}}\Sigma^{\frac{1}{2}}A\Sigma^{\frac{1}{2}}\Sigma^{-\frac{1}{2}}Y$=

$Y^{T}\Sigma^{-\frac{1}{2}}PDP^{T}\Sigma^{-\frac{1}{2}}Y$.

Presumably, $PDP^{T}$ is the spectral decomposition of $A$. Then, why is it replacing $\Sigma^{\frac{1}{2}}A\Sigma^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and not $A$ itself?

Comment: On what is your "presumably" based?  It contradicts this step in the proof, where it appears that $PDP^\prime$ diagonalizes $\Sigma^{1/2}A\Sigma^{1/2},$ not $A.$

Comment: How do we know that  Σ1/2Σ1/2 can be diagonalized?

Comment: Presumably $A$ is symmetric and also presumably the version of "$\Sigma^{1/2}$" you are using is a product of an orthogonal matrix and a diagonal matrix.